# Benchmarking Wasm error

Tags: benchmarking, wasm, error

I am trying to do benchmarking for my pallet,but I get the following error:

```
 Error executing and verifying runtime benchmark: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
WASM backtrace:

    0: 0x1a301b - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0x30a5 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h6a131cbcc658ec37
    2: 0x361a - <unknown>!core::panicking::assert_failed_inner::h86b3069f7ca9f7fb
    3: 0x87700 - <unknown>!core::panicking::assert_failed::h6b8055eba7e8280d
    4: 0xd528b - <unknown>!core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}::h929d29dd14df6479
    5: 0x185359 - <unknown>!pallet_nft::benchmarking::<impl frame_benchmarking::utils::Benchmarking for pallet_nft::pallet::Pallet<T>>::run_benchmark::h62db5691578e2bd7
    6: 0xe4eba - <unknown>!<fs_node_runtime::Runtime as frame_benchmarking::utils::runtime_decl_for_Benchmark::Benchmark<sp_runtime::generic::block::Block<sp_runtime::generic::header::Header<u32,sp_runtime::traits::BlakeTwo256>,sp_runtime::generic::unchecked_extrinsic::UncheckedExtrinsic<sp_runtime::multiaddress::MultiAddress<<<sp_runtime::MultiSignature as sp_runtime::traits::Verify>::Signer as sp_runtime::traits::IdentifyAccount>::AccountId,()>,fs_node_runtime::Call,sp_runtime::MultiSignature,(frame_system::extensions::check_non_zero_sender::CheckNonZeroSender<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>,pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>)>>>>::dispatch_benchmark::h1ae5618b1e790929
    7: 0x149bd5 - <unknown>!Benchmark_dispatch_benchmark
```

Any Idea on how to interpret this error, or even better: solve it?
Kazu

Comment: Could you please try to run the benchmarking tests of your pallet?
`cargo t -p pallet-nft --features runtime-benchmarks`

Comment: Thank you! the problem was indeed a failing test in the benchmarking!!!

Comment: Okay good. I will copy it into an answer so we can close this question and other people will find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a failing test in your benchmarks. The error message looks a bit scary if you did not try to run them manually first.
Try:

```sh
cargo t -p pallet-nft --features runtime-benchmarks
```