# Another Benchmarking Wasm error

Tags: benchmarking, wasm, error

I asked a similar question a month ago [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4372/benchmarking-wasm-error?noredirect=1#comment4139_4372), and the answer/explanation was found in a failing `cargo t -p pallet-nft --features runtime-benchmarks` command.
This time, the building part works, the testing (command above) succeded, but in the end I get the following error

```
Error executing and verifying runtime benchmark: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
WASM backtrace:

    0: 0x3940eb - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0x4097 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::hc0f1a745489a812e
    2: 0x4058 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic::h8bed5bf163926af5
    3: 0x2b21c5 - <unknown>!pallet_onboarding::functions::<impl pallet_onboarding::pallet::Pallet<T>>::status::hc38e51a95e1f40c3
    4: 0x193b6c - <unknown>!frame_support::storage::transactional::with_transaction::h52bc32ba1bfdf570
    5: 0x595a4 - <unknown>!<pallet_share_distributor::benchmarking::SelectedBenchmark as frame_benchmarking::utils::BenchmarkingSetup<T>>::instance::ha831dc7a67fa6d5e
    6: 0x30ec9a - <unknown>!pallet_share_distributor::benchmarking::<impl frame_benchmarking::utils::Benchmarking for pallet_share_distributor::pallet::Pallet<T>>::run_benchmark::h31fd450e96802663
    7: 0x203708 - <unknown>!<fs_node_runtime::Runtime as frame_benchmarking::utils::runtime_decl_for_Benchmark::Benchmark<sp_runtime::generic::block::Block<sp_runtime::generic::header::Header<u32,sp_runtime::traits::BlakeTwo256>,sp_runtime::generic::unchecked_extrinsic::UncheckedExtrinsic<sp_runtime::multiaddress::MultiAddress<<<sp_runtime::MultiSignature as sp_runtime::traits::Verify>::Signer as sp_runtime::traits::IdentifyAccount>::AccountId,()>,fs_node_runtime::Call,sp_runtime::MultiSignature,(frame_system::extensions::check_non_zero_sender::CheckNonZeroSender<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_spec_version::CheckSpecVersion<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_tx_version::CheckTxVersion<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_genesis::CheckGenesis<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_mortality::CheckMortality<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_nonce::CheckNonce<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>,frame_system::extensions::check_weight::CheckWeight<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>,pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<fs_node_runtime::Runtime>)>>>>::dispatch_benchmark::h43f9fdd5b8f895d2
    8: 0x3466be - <unknown>!Benchmark_dispatch_benchmark
```

Any idea on How to fix it please?

**EDIT:**

I get the error after executing the following command
`./target/release/fs-node benchmark pallet --chain dev --execution=wasm --wasm-execution=compiled --pallet pallet_share_distributor --extrinsic * --steps 100 --repeat 40 --output pallets/share_distributor/src/weights.rs --template assets/frame-weight-template.hbs`

Comment: Which command did you run? Please consider marking the other question as "Answered" then.

Comment: Could be a difference between your mock runtime and the node runtime, since it works with the tests but not the node. Cannot suggest more without source-code.